# Entorno de desarrollo nativo para bases de datos Firebird

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird

Estoy buscando un entorno de desarrollo nativo para bases de datos Firebird, es decir un SQL Server Management para SQL Server o MySQL Workbench para MySQL.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que hay para Bases de Datos Interbase o Firebird es [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/).
Puedes descargar la versión "personal" gratuita para probar la mayoría de funcionalidades y si te convence comprar la versión profesional.

De todos los que he probado es el mejor con mucho.